# IE8 Bug with pseudo elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, pseudo-element, css-position

I've isolated a strange issue with IE8 regarding the CSS `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements. The issue occurs when you set one pseudo elements position to absolute and the other's to relative; see the following example:

```
<style type="text/css">
  div:before { content: ""; position: relative; }
  div:after { content: ""; position: absolute; }
</style>
<div>stuff</div>
```

IE8 crashes. Literally. No error, nothing helpful - just the dreaded "Internet Explorer has stopped working" and the Windows 7 attempt to relaunch it. To be clear, the error occurs when switching to the IE8 Browser and Rendering Mode of IE9. When i loaded the example in IETester's IE8 page, no error occurred.

I will test this in an actual IE8 asap, but my question is: why does this happen? Is it an IE8 bug? Maybe a side effect of some sort of `position` bug? Isn't IE8 supposed to render pseudo elements?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that's weird.  I was able to get it to work if you make it `float:left;` on the `div:before`

Comment: +1 this is useful information - but it doesn't fully answer my question. What's going on here?

Comment: The only thing I can sort of come up with is the IE will try to bind `position:relative;` to anything not declared, and since we have `:before` setup, it's trying to bind it to something that doesn't "exist" and it's crashing it.  I can't see any errors on mine, it just crashes as well.

Comment: if you mean what i think you mean: adding `position:relative;` to the containing element didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old.. but I had the same problem and fixed it with "div::after" instead of "div:after"